# packet flow for connections to 127.0.0.0/8 network

Tags: netfilter

I have a following very simple `iptables` configuration:

```
# iptables -n -v -L INPUT --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 21 packets, 1683 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        4   336 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
#
```

As seen above, I don't explicitly allow connections to 127/8 network and thus while I receive for example ICMP `echo reply` messages from `8.8.8.8`, I don't receive anything if I ping 127.0.0.1(configured to `lo` interface):

```
# ping -qc4 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.247/5.305/5.357/0.099 ms
# ping -qc4 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3024ms

#
```

Why aren't packets sent to 127.0.0.1 matched by this `iptables` rule which accept established and related connections?

Comment: Can you ping your physical interface local IP?

Comment: @heemayl Not with that single `-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` rule. Once I add `-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT` rule, then I'm able to ping physical interface local IP.